# Ускорение записи в бд в Python

Tags: python, sqlite, оптимизация, python-2.x

Здравствуйте.

Не спрашивайте зачем, но мне нужно записать в бд числа от 1000000000000 до 9999999999999.

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('db.db')
c = conn.cursor()

d = 1000000000000

for x in xrange(8999999999999):
    d += 1

    sql = 'INSERT INTO number (d) VALUES("' + str(d) + '")'
    c.execute(sql)
    print d

conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Работает скрипт медленно. Такими темпами он будет работать с неделю. Как можно ускорить?

P.S. Спасибо Timofey Bondarev. Подсказал про xrange и про вынесение commit за цикл. Может ещё можно как-то оптимизировать?

Comment: Можно только в корне пересмотреть задачу, так, чтобы нужные (не спрашиваю зачем) числа не хранились в базе, а *вычислялись* (по одному?) перед использованием. (См. мой комментарий к ответу @Timofey Bondarev).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Не знаю, относится ли проблема к БД, но в коде, непосредственно составляющем запрос определённо можно внести улучшения:

В Python 2 вместо `range` стоит использовать `xrange`, если вам не нужен непосредственно сам список.

Определённо не стоит делать `commit` после каждой записи в базу, достаточно сделать его после цикла.

---

**Update**

Возможно, есть смысл сделать это одним выражением, это нужно проверять на реальном примере:

```
query = ('INSERT INTO number (d) VALUES ' +  
         ','.join('("%s")' % x for x in xrange(1000000000000, 10000000000000)));

c.execute(query)
conn.commit()
```

Ну и конечно же, даже если это не поможет, нет смысла управлять вручную переменной `d`, достаточно передать правильные аргументы в `xrange`: `xrange(1000000000000, 10000000000000)` как раз сгенерирует нужную последовательность чисел.

Comment: Спасибо. Про xrange не знал, а вот про commit сам подумал. Получается что он потом просто сохраняет большую транзакцию. Может ещё что посоветуете?

Comment: @temagr, да, сохранить одну большую транзакцию проще, чем сохранять такое большое количество малых.

Comment: Кстати, как вы думаете, если перестать выводить число каждый раз, это сильно ускорит работу?

Comment: Да, это может довольно неплохо ускорить, конечно. При желании вы можете выводить каждые 10000.

Comment: @temagr обратите внимание на обновление

Comment: Одним запросом не получится, длина запроса составит больше 100 терабайт. Надо делать вложенный цикл и вставлять по 10-100-1000 записей, вот тут надо уже подбирать сколько одним махом можно вставить строк

Comment: кстати, если числа именно такие, вы прикидывали объем полученной базы? 8999999999999 записей int64 (8 байт) это минимум 71999999999992 байт = 65 Тб

Comment: @Tunker это да, пожалуй я не доглядел =)

Comment: @temagr, коллеги, **посчитайте немного!** / Даже без всякой базы 899999999999 чисел в строковом виде (по 14 байт на число) займут 125000 **терабайтных дисков** (а они у вас есть?). / А вот оптимистическая оценка времени записи (при скорости 100 MB/sec (для "сырой" записи на диск это вполне реально)) оказывается чуть больше 2-х недель, что близко к неделе, которая пугает ТС (ну а с СУБД я даже боюсь предполагать память-время, которые потребуются). / Кстати, время будет определяться именно скоростью записи на носитель, так что программу можно не менять. / Думаю, все с этой задачкой очевидно...